# New to Xamarin, I don't understand the project structure

Tags: xamarin

I have a project where i'm asked to develop in xamarin. The problem is that I don't really understand the structure. There're Project, Project.Android and Project.IOS folders. If i code in Project, then what are the 2 other folders for ?

I think it's to code specific parts that can't be in Project, but how do you include them ? If there's a good youtube tutorial for that i would be thankful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows

Comment: Look up Xamarin Forms beginners tutorials
Project is your app's code Project.Android and Project.IOS are Platform-specific  generated code from your Project code + any Platform-specific code you write there yourself

Comment: You could refer to the link below. It describes what the xamarin.forms is and what is the Platform-specifics is of Project.Android and Project.IOS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms#platform-specifics

Answer (score 0):

it is never late to start with any technology let me answer your question as you said there are 3 folders

> YourProject
>
> YourProject.Android
>
> YourProject.IOS

when you work on xamarin your 70-80% of your code is reused but some things are always platform specific

when we talk about YourProject.Android or YourProject.IOS they are platform specific implementations

in this folders you can add code for hardware based implementation, using platform specific features, Designing controls differently for platforms(Custom Renderer) and much more

in case of any such doubts i would suggest you to go through the official documentation of xamarin

Link to Document [Official Xamarin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)